# Differentiability theorem and $\frac{xy}{x^{2}+y^{2}}$ when $(x,y)\neq 0$ and $0$ for $(x,y)=0$

Tags: calculus, multivariable-calculus

I was looking at this function $\frac{xy}{x^{2}+y^{2}}$ when $(x,y)\neq 0$ and $0$ for $(x,y)=0$ and I hope to clear up some confusion. It seems to satisfy the following theorem:

> Theorem: If a function $F:\mathbb{R}^{n}\rightarrow \mathbb{R}^{m}$ has existing partial derivatives in some open set $A\subset \mathbb{R}^{n}$ and has the partials continuous at some point $a\in A$ then $F$ is differentiable at a.

Its partial derivatives seem to be continuous at $(0,0)$ as the limit appear to approach 0 from all directions. They clearly exist in any open ball around $(0,0)$ as well. Hence by the theorem $F$ should be differentiable at $(0,0)$. However, this function is not even continuous at $(0,0)$. I was wondering then why this theorem seems to fail in this particular case.

Proofs I've seen of this theorem invoke the mean value theorem component by component meaning that $F$ ought to be at least component wise continuous and differentiable. This seems to be satisfied by the existence of all partial derivatives in an open ball as seen in the hypothesis of the theorem. The only thing I see falling apart in the example I have given above is that $F$ is not continuous at $(0,0)$ but continuity of the entire function does not seem to be a necessary assumption for this theorem.
Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: If the conclusion of a theorem is false, at least one hypothesis must be false. Your first task is to identify which hypothesis is false; that involves looking more carefully at why that hypothesis "seems to be true." :)

Comment: The theorem as it stands is misstated and wrong. The partial derivatives need to be continuous at $a$. Also, please include all the crucial information in the body of the question. The function in the title *is* continuous at the origin. Please proofread and revise.

Comment: @TedShifrin My apologies for any confusion, I had meant to say the partial derivatives exist and are continuous at a. Also, I believe $\frac{xy}{x^{2}+y^{2}}$ has a limit of $\frac{1}{2}$ on the line $x=y$ and has a limit of $0$ elsewhere meaning it is not continuous at the origin.

Comment: No, you can always edit your own posts. What you just said us correct, but your function has a factor of $x$.

Comment: Yes sorry I found the edit button, I hope it is more clear now.

Comment: Oh, so you changed the function. OK, it is not continuous at the origin, but nor are the partial derivatives continuous!

Comment: Interestingly, existence of the partial derivatives in a neighborhood implies continuity of the function in the coordinate directions. This is all that’s needed to apply the Mean Value Theorem coordinate by coordinate.

Comment: @TedShifrin could I get a hint as to find out why the partials are not continuous at the origin? I have tried taking the limit on the axis and on the line $y=x$. I got this problem from a book that said this function is an example where the partial derivatives are continuous which is why I am confused.

Comment: You can’t just take two lines and say you’re done. Edit your post to. Include the partial derivative. And more examination!

Comment: Trying to follow the back and forth since there were multiple edits and some comments pertain to an incorrect statement and conclusion.  The function is not continuous at (0,0) therefore cannot be differentiable, so some assumption must fail, so is it that the partials are not continuous at (0,0)? They both have $x^2+y^2$ in the denominator, so they are not even defined at (0,0).

Comment: @AlgTop1854 Your last comment is irrelevant. The function is defined to be $0$ at $0$. Both partial derivatives at the origin are $0$.

Comment: Thank you I realize that now! So it just comes down to showing the partials are not continuous there.

Comment: Ok I think I have got it now, thanks!

Answer (score 1):

The answer is essentially given in the comments but in case anyone else would find this useful:

$$F_{x}=\frac{(x^{2}+y^{2})(y)-(xy)(2x)}{(x^{2}+y^{2})^{2}}$$ Taking the limit on the curve $x=\sqrt{y}$ then $F_{x}=\frac{y-1}{(y+1)^{2}}$ which in the limit is $-1$ at $(0,0)$ meaning the partial derivatives are not actually continuous at $(0,0)$. The same can be said for $F_{y}$.

Comment: Do we need another contour or the fact that $\partial f/\partial x(0,0)=0?$

Comment: I think it is enough that the partial derivative is $0$ since that would break continuity from the definition.

Answer (score 0):

$f(x,y)=\frac{xy}{x^2+y^2}$ for $(x,y)\neq(0,0)$; $f(0,0)=0$. Then, $f(x,y)$ is not continous at $(0,0)$ but partial derivatives exist at the origin and $f_x(0,0)=f_y(0,0)=0.$ If the stated theorem is true, at least one of the partial derivatives must be discontinuous at the origin. The partial derivative with respect to $x$ is
$$f_x=\frac{\partial f}{\partial x}=\frac{y^3-x^2y}{(x^2+y^2)^2}.$$
We show that it is not continuous at the origin by choosing two different contours for the limit $L=\lim_{(x,y)\to (0,0)}f_x$:

$C_1(y=0)$: $L_1=\lim_{x\to 0}\frac0{x^4}=0.$

$C_2 (x=0)$: $L_2=\lim_{y\to 0}\frac1y$ does not exists. We are done. No need to $C_1$.